# YTD measure only on Current Month

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create YTD that could only show on current month(Dec21 I have considered as Current month) on matrix PowerBI. I have multiple month in matrix, but I want YTD on current month not on all month. Is this doable? If so can someone help please. Below is sample for my question.
[image]

Comment: try with if statement; pseudocode

if( SELECTEDVALUE(Table[YearMonth]) = currentMonth; [YourYTDmeasure]; BLANK())

Comment: Hi,
Thank you.
By doing this it will create blank YTD column in previous months. Is there a way to filter blank YTD columns of previous months?